# Understanding partity flag in a cmp instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, att, eflags

I think I'm not quite understanding what the `PF` is in the eflags register. Here are two comparisons I have done to see how it works:

```
 # a > b -- 0b01
 mov $4, %rax
 mov $3, %rbx
 cmp %rax, %rbx  # [ CF PF AF SF IF ] *PF* included

 # a > b -- 0b10
 mov $5, %rax
 mov $3, %rbx
 cmp %rax, %rbx  # [ CF AF SF IF ]

 # a = b -- 0b00
 mov $5, %rax
 mov $5, %rbx
 cmp %rax, %rbx  # [ PF ZF IF ] *PF* included
```

In the first operation, the comparison would produce `1` or `0x01` and in the second it would produce `2` or `0x10`. Why then is the parity flag set in the first one but not the second one, since both of them have one bit set to 1.

Comment: `3-4 = 0xffffffffffffffff`.  An even number of bits set in the low byte.  Don't forget, this is AT&T syntax

Comment: @PeterCordes I see. But why does it do the operation as `4-3` instead of `3-4` for the comparison?

Comment: It doesn't do `4-3`.  It does `3-4`.  AT&T syntax is always destination-last, operand list reversed vs. Intel syntax.  So `cmp %rax, %rbx` is like `sub %rax, %rbx` but without modifying the destination (RBX).  It would be even more weird if instructions like `cmp` didn't have their operand-lists reversed.

Comment: @PeterCordes got it -- that's a bit tricky actually, thanks for clarifying how the `cmp` works in doing the flags.